# Hyper-V 2012R2 Get VM snapshot file with powershell

Tags: powershell, snapshot, hyper-v

I got a powershell script to generate an HTML report includes all VM's and snapshots of one hyper-v server.

At first I get all vms with `Get-VM`. Then I loop through that list and get all snapshots for one vm with `Get-VMSnapshot`.

The problem that I got is, that i can't see how I get from `$VMSnapshot` to the real file to get its size.

Here is my code:

```
$VMs = Get-VM -ComputerName $Computers
foreach ($VM in $VMs) {
    $VMSnapshots = Get-VMSnapshot -VMName $VM.VMName -ComputerName $VM.ComputerName | Select ComputerName, VMNAME, CreationTime, Path, Name | sort CreationTime
    foreach ($VMSnapshot in $VMSnapshots) {
        #How to get the filesize of that snapshot?
    }
}
```

I know, that its possible to get the filesize with `$VMSnapshotSize gci -Path $VMSnapshot.Path -Filter *.avhd*`, but than I don't have relationship between `$VMSnapshot` and `$VMSnapshotSize` since there is more than one snapshot in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Get-VMSnapshot -VMName $VM.VMName | select -ExpandProperty HardDrives | % { Get-VHD $_.Path | select Path, FileSize }
```